# Does the US government have a plan to aid people in poverty displaced by climate change?

Tags: united-states, climate-change

Say that the sea level rises due to climate change and an area in the US becomes uninhabitable. Perhaps an island is now underwater or a coast line creeps inward. This would displace a number of people who live there, and those in poverty would be unlikely to have the resources to move.

Does the US have a plan to provide any sort of aid, financial or otherwise, to help such displaced people in poverty?

<sub>I am asking about if the US has a contingency plan in place for those displaced due to climate change, and do not want to argue whether climate change is actually occurring.</sub>

Comment: Lot of "what if" that are far into the future, if they happen at all.

Comment: @Sjoerd Aren't there some islands that are owned by the US that are not very high above sea level? I would think that people living on those islands would be affected sooner than later.

Comment: Have you checked the IPCC projections? 25-82 cm rise by 2100. I think most islands can handle a rise of less than a yard without trouble, while a coast line change of a few meters won't affect many people either.

Comment: Is there a reason you think they should have?

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom Please give an example of such a place.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Maldives. highest elevation two meters.

Comment: @MSalters Maldives are not USA - this is about USA islands.

Comment: @sjoerd: South Beach, FL has an average elevation of less than 1 meter. Much of coastal Florida is manifestly already troubled by flooding due to sea rise. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_flooding), [NOAA Office for Coastal Management](https://coast.noaa.gov/states/fast-facts/recurrent-tidal-flooding.html), [Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/flooding-sea-level-rise-cost-town-100000s-in-lost-income-2019-2) and many other sources documenting problems and financial costs.

Comment: Just a note about government plans, but planning is super easy and barely an inconvenience.   In fact, one of the easiest ways to draft plans is let some low level grunt do it.   It teaches them how to make plans and once made, it costs nothing to maintain them.   The U.S. currently has plans for an invasion by (in order of most to least likely to occur) extraterrestrials, Canadians, Mexicans (the government, not migrant citizens of) and the Girl Scouts of America (seriously debating if they are less likely then Canada). +

Comment: +The Pacific Theater of World War II largely went according to plans the U.S. Military drafted some two decades prior to the Japanese attack on Pearl Harbor!   So yes, there's probably plans for what to do if flooding exceeds even the worst case scenarios of predictions (and keep in mind, Climate Change models have predicting doom and gloom in a decade since four decades ago... so it's likely not going to be as bad as you think it will be.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer turns out to be yes and no. Plans are, in general, not addressed at people *in poverty*, but at specific situations.

Furthermore, plans do not specifically address "climate change", seeing as that is a somewhat political term, but address specific changes to the landscape. Whether or not these changes are caused by climate change is basically left up to the reader.

So, in short, the answer to your question, specifically, is:

> *No*, there are no plans addressed at *people* *in poverty* *displaced* by
>   *climate change*.

There are of course enough plans addressed at sites that have environmental or landscape-related problems.

For example: https://floridadep.gov/water/beaches

Last but not least, there are some emergency plans addressed at climate change:

https://www.fema.gov/climate-change

Comment: [USACE also has plans for climate-change](https://www.usace.army.mil/Portals/2/docs/civilworks/climate/docs/EC_1165-2-212-Final_10_Nov_2011.pdf?ver=2017-11-30-111654-607). If you read through the USACE's plans and site, you'll see they are concerned less with the political implications of Climate Change (the why) as they are with the actual results of a trend of warmer Arctic and Antarctic weather (climate change) causing rising water levels (the what).

Comment: I have this annoying feeling that I generally like your answer, but think that it needs expanding. FEMA already subsidises insurance of buildings on floodplains, so in case of making some areas clearly uninhabitable as requested in the question, at least those people would be fine as they would cash out the insurance.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Why? because this is not something that the US is likely to have to face during the current elected term of the officials.  Our elected officials have shown that they are unwilling to tackle problems that are likely to be faced in the future where they will not have to face election.  Instead they will wait until the problem has occurred and then point fingers and hope that someone else deals with the problem so they can claim credit.

Second, there is no real way to predict actual needs.  The government has a bad habit of drastically under or over estimating the needs of a catastrophe. The Army Corps of Engineers has a plan for dealing with pretty much any increase in water levels in the near term (4-8 years) that are not the result of an unexpected storm or event.  That is as close as it comes to this type of preparation in the US by the government.

Comment: Please include a citation for ACOE 4-8yr water level plans.

Comment: @agc I know they have them because they are maintained by the USCGA

Comment: [Actually it does have plans for Ocean level changes](https://www.usace.army.mil/corpsclimate/Planning_for_Changing_Sea_Levels/) due to [Climate Change](https://www.usace.army.mil/Portals/2/docs/civilworks/climate/docs/EC_1165-2-212-Final_10_Nov_2011.pdf?ver=2017-11-30-111654-607)

Comment: @JJJ wow, completely muffed Corps... and I used to be in an Army Corps.